# Cross browser testing code

Tags: drupal-7, cross-browser

i have created a drupal site while testing my css on google chrome.Now, i want to make this drupal site look the same on every other browser. what i need is - how to do this without changing my css or maybe add certain code so that this site takes same quirks like chrome as every other browser.

Comment: You made a custom theme from scratch?

Comment: yes i made a custom theme from scratch.

Comment: This is an HTML/CSS/JS question and does not have to do with Drupal!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid your cross browser problem, it's better to create a [sub-theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/1978010) from a good minimalistic starting theme like Bootstrap.

But in your case, and because it's too late, I suggest you to insert a piece of CSS code that will normalize the values in all browsers: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Hope it helped.